# IPad navigation controller toolbar position

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a `UIViewController` inside of `UINavigationViewController`. I use `navigationController`.`toolbar` for some actions.

[image: Before]

There's no problem until the first device rotation. After it toolbar goes off the screen frame.

[image: After]

And there's nothing to be done, even another device rotations can't fix this.
The problem occurs only on IPad ios v.6.
The code is very simple:

```
- (void)createToolbar{
   UIImage *toolbarBack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)];
   [self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundImage:toolbarBack forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   self.navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self;
   //...
   self.toolbarItems = @[item1, space, item2, space, item3, space, item4];
}

- (void)showToolbar{
   [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark - toolbar delegate methods

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar{
   return UIBarPositionBottom;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I found out that before the rotation navigationController.view.height == 1004 and after the rotations it increase by 20 (1024). Is it some statusbar issue?

Comment: I guess you have a bad constraint, which is pushing your toolbar to deep in your view.

Comment: Can you paste your code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up toolbar delegate to your view controller and implement method:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionBottom;
}
```

If you use storyboard you can create constraint between bottom of the screen and your toolbar.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use autolayout.
Using toolbar delegate methods doesn't making a sense.

Comment: So just implement above method and in viewDidLoad add navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self. Don't remember add protocol <UIToolbarDelegate>.

Comment: I have implemented protocol method but it made no defference

Comment: I don't set up tollbar frame. I just set a position ([self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundImage:toolbarBack forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];) and it appears on bottom.

Comment: Try set frame in layoutSubview method to stick your nav bar on the bottom of the screen: screen height - navBar height.

Comment: Setting toolbar's delegate throws an exception: 'Cannot manually set the delegate on a UIToolbar managed by a controller.'